Does adding a reflector to a patio heater cause a safety hazard?
I have recently bought and installed a patio heater. The heat output and the height adjustable function makes it workable for my balcony. I also bought a reflector from a different company, as I read that this will help make the head more directional. But now that everything is installed, I'm having doubts about whether the reflector is a good idea or not.
As shown in the picture of how the heater is set up, the reflector directs the reflected heat to the lower perforated sheet part where the ignitor and the gas valve is.
My concern is that I can't really see what is inside this lower part, and even though the lower perforated sheet doesn't warm up, it doesn't mean whatever is inside will not. Is this a safety concern?


No worries.  The reflector will heat the outside of the center perforated part on the side facing it the most.  If it doesn’t get hot, nothing inside will because the screen blocks most of the heat, plus there’s an updraft of cool air rising over and through it caused by convection currents feeding the burner above it.
I would keep a eye on the ceiling, however, as hot air rises from convection and heat is radiated upward from the top OEM shield.  If ceiling gets too hot to touch, you can attach a heat reflector to it (thin aluminum would do nicely).  You would also get a little more heat reflected down where you want it.
(I have had one for years, and assembled and maintained a dozen or so for a local animal shelter.  Some have been under low roofs, similar to the deck above your balcony.)

I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. You make a positive assertion followed by a big if.  You haven't convinced me that you aren't simply speculating.

@isherwood - “if” is not speculative as used here, for it refers to OP’s assertion that “the lower perforated sheet doesn't warm up”.  As for heat flow, I accept your pedantic gauntlet and respond in kind:  I maintain that heat does indeed flow, and in three main ways:  one, as you say, is by radiation; and additionally by conduction and convection. Heat is energy, and when hot air rises by convection, its heat energy goes up with it.  “Heat rises” may sometimes be, as you assert (and I would agree), used incorrectly.  Yet in this instance, it is a useful shorthand that is technically correct.

It'll probably be fine; but it could undoubtedly cause issues. It's a modification to the patio heater that'll invalidate some of the safety testing done on it, it won't just reflect heat but also disrupt the airflow pattern potentially increasing CO production or making it malfunction in windy conditions.
Honestly I'd be a little wary about using a portable gas-fired patio heater on a balcony at all; although they have safety systems and ought to shut off if tipped over there's still always a risk of fire with a live flame and a balcony is not a great place to have a fire - it could spread very easily into your or your neighbours apartments. If you're somewhere that gets storms there's also the risk your heater could be damaged or even blown out of the balcony by the wind.
A permanently fixed electric IR heater would be much safer - they come with reflectors built in and would also be economical to run without having to buy bottled fuel.
